# How to prevent DDOS with TCPCT without client side support?

Tags: network-protocols

I read the RFC 6013 about the TCP Cookie Transactions. Actually the cookie transaction could prevent DDOS. But it is just one TCP option. It needs both of client and server support it at the same time. But why the client uses this option if he is a malicious attacker?

I don't think the TCP Cookie Transactions could prevent DDOS

If client doesn't use the option, how the TCPCT prevent the DDOS?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible answers to your question, but this is probably the simplest: Once TCPCT is widely-adopted, during a DDOS attack, you can reject all connections that don't use TCPCT. Thus legitimate connections with clients that support TCPCT will continue to work, defeating the DDOS attack.

Comment: Thanks. I considered this method before. But once the server forbids the client which does not support TCPCT. It may reject too many clients. Because most clients will not be upgraded in time.

Comment: sorry, I reply slowly. I mean most clients will not be upgrade to support the TCPCT. Then it is impossible to server limit only the client which supports TCPCT could connect it.

Answer (score 0):

Good Answer from @David Schwartz but I don`t see how this can prevent botnet DDoS which actually uses "legitimate" infected machines. (i.e. Trojan DDoS) 
These are fairly common attack tactics - easily used and cheaply purchased. This is just one of many resources on the subject:

http://www.scmagazine.com/easily-available-tools-botnets-contribute-to-ddos-rise/article/253382/

Yes, TCP Cookie can prevent SYN Floods but these are already can be mitigated by ACK verification (and preferably reverse proxy to hold off bigger floods)

I work for a security company ([Incapsula](http://www.incapsula.com/)) and we deal with DDoS on a daily basis. We prevent lots of botnet attacks and the numbers/attack sizes are only continue to grow.

I think that, in next 3-5 years, most SMB commercial sites will have 3rd party DDoS protection in place as this is all just a race (attack volume vs pipe size) and a 3rd party front-gate proxy is the most cost-effective way to have a scalable and efficient DDoS solution.

Comment: The purpose is not to prevent DDoS attacks but to reduce the damage they do. This will reduce the damage even from 'legitimate' infected machines because they won't be able to spoof their IP addresses, meaning they'll either have to limit to one connection per address or attacking connections can be separated from the majority of legitimate connections, drastically reducing the effectiveness of the attack.